# Complex objects with redis-py

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I've been using the redis-cli to get the hang of how redis works. I understand that using this tool I can do this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set post:1:title "Redis is cool!"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set post:1:author "haye321"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get post:1:title
"Redis is cool!"
```

What I cannot seem to figure out is how I would accomplish this with redis-py. It doesn't seem the `set` commanded provided allows for an object-type or id. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting individual fields of a Redis hash one by one (a hash is the common data structure in Redis to store objects).

A better way to do this is to use Redis [HMSET](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) command, that allows to set multiple fields of a given hash in one operation. Using Redis-py it will look like this:

```
import redis
redisdb = redis.Redis(host="localhost",db=1)
redisdb.hmset('post:1', {'title':'Redis is cool!', 'author':'haye321'})
```

**update:**

Of course you could have set Hash field members one by one using the [HSET](http://redis.io/commands/hset) command, but it's less efficient as it requires one request per field:

```
import redis
redisdb = redis.Redis(host="localhost",db=1)
redisdb.hset('post:1', 'title', 'Redis is cool!')
redisdb.hset('post:1', 'author', 'haye321'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I increment to the next available post id if I was using hashes?

Comment: Use Redis INCR command to get unique IDs the concatenate them with your 'post:' key.

Comment: How do I pass the "post": key to the INCR command? Sorry for being difficult but an example would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: You really should read [Redis introduction documentation](http://redis.io/topics/introduction) and follow the [interactive tutorial](http://try.redis.io/).

Comment: I have read the Redis documentation, extensively. I don't feel that it does a good job of explaining the distinctions at play here. I found this link to be very helpful for someone in my position. http://joshtronic.com/2013/07/29/mysql-and-redis-command-equivalents/#.Ux1ST-ddXHL

Comment: [This tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone) will show you how to use INCR to generate IDs to be included in your keys.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: you can use `RedisWorks` library.

`pip install redisworks`

```
>>> from redisworks import Root
>>> root = Root()
>>> root.item1 = {'title':'Redis is cool!', 'author':'haye321'}
>>> print(root.item1)  # reads it from Redis
{'title':'Redis is cool!', 'author':'haye321'}
```

And if you really need to use `post.1` as key name in Redis:

```
>>> class Post(Root):
...     pass
... 
>>> post=Post()
>>> post.i1 = {'title':'Redis is cool!', 'author':'haye321'}
>>> print(post.i1)
{'author': 'haye321', 'title': 'Redis is cool!'}
>>>
```

If you check Redis

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> type post.1
hash
```